# Android MaterialButton doesn't update icon to its tintColor when parent is invisible

Tags: android, material-components-android

I use MaterialButton as an style toggle for rich editor. I noticed that on some devices icon drawable is not updated when panel with buttons was invisible (or not added to view) during inflation.

I use selector as icontTint `toggle_fg_selector`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:color="?attr/colorPrimaryLight" />

    <item
        android:state_activated="true"
        android:color="?attr/colorPrimaryLight" />

    <item
        android:color="?attr/colorSecondaryTint" />
</selector>
```

My buttons:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/note_bar_size"
    android:background="?colorPrimaryLight">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/note_bold_button"
        style="@style/AcTheme.IconOnlyButton"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/actionbar_buttons_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/actionbar_buttons_size"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/actionbar_buttons_gat"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/toggle_bg_selector"
        app:backgroundTint="@null"
        app:icon="@drawable/icbf_bold"
        app:iconTint="@drawable/toggle_fg_selector" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/note_italic_button"
        style="@style/AcTheme.IconOnlyButton"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/actionbar_buttons_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/actionbar_buttons_size"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/actionbar_buttons_gat"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/toggle_bg_selector"
        app:backgroundTint="@null"
        app:icon="@drawable/icbf_italic"
        app:iconTint="@drawable/toggle_fg_selector" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/note_strike_button"
        style="@style/AcTheme.IconOnlyButton"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/actionbar_buttons_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/actionbar_buttons_size"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/actionbar_buttons_gat"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/toggle_bg_selector"
        app:backgroundTint="@null"
        app:icon="@drawable/icbf_strike"
        app:iconTint="@drawable/toggle_fg_selector" />
        .....
```

But when I uncheck and check the button again, drawable is tinted correctly based on its checked state:
[image]

This bug is reproduced when firstly `button.isChecked = true|false` was set when panel with toggle buttons was invisible.
How can I achieve desired tinting on every device in spite of whether `isChecked` is set with visible or invisible parent?

Comment: By the way, I think `ToggleButton` is more suitable for your case, just set `android:textOn="@null"` and `android:textOff="@null"` and apply the custom selector `Drawable` as background. Using `MaterialButton` just too complicated and not neccessary.

Comment: @SamChen I actually have tried `ToggleButton`, but its attribute `drawableTint` is only available on API >= 23, (but I need 21). Also same issue was with `AppCompatToggleButton` with `app:drawableTint`

Comment: What do you do with the `drawableTint` attribute?

Comment: @SamChen tint the icon of the ToggleButton according to button state (checked|not checked)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing **BackgroundTint** from xml.

Comment: I need tintable background as well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you didn't provide the default (unchecked) state color for the iconTint.

Try this:

```
<selector 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:color="?attr/colorPrimaryLight" />     //checked state color

    <item
        android:state_checked="false"                  //here!! Unchecked state color
        android:color="@android:color/transparent" />  //"@null" doesn't work!!

</selector>
```

Comment: Wait a minute, doesn't this line `<item android:color="?attr/colorSecondaryTint" />` do the thing ?

Comment: @Oleksandr Albul Color is different.